# NVD3 (D3 JS) how to remove y2 axis

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to use the following example which is a line and bar chart combined.

[NVD3 Line & Bar Chart combination](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html)

The problem I have is that I want the line chart and bar chart to both use the same figures from y1 axis, but I can't find out how to get rid of the y2 axis and do this.

If someone could point me in the right direction it'd be a great help.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

A JSFiddle of the problem I'm experiencing. I'm just using the example from NVD3's download and have added in Lars' code just before the `return chart;` line.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S43qg/8/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no option to disable the second y axis. What you can do is set it up to have the same scale as the y1 axis and then remove it after creating the graph, i.e.

```
d3.select('.nv-y2.nv-axis').remove();
```

This will leave some empty space where the axis used to be, but at least it'll create the impression that there's only one y axis.

Comment: Thanks, that helps remove the second axis at least. Is it possible to change the line to use the same scale as Y1?

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like `chart.y2Axis.scale(chart.y1Axis.scale());`.

Comment: `chart.y2Axis.scale().domain(chart.y1Axis.scale().domain());` at the very end (just before returning the chart) works for me.

Comment: That's weird, I've tried doing exactly that but it hasn't made any change again. I also tried it in the original example downloads in case I'd done something and also on their live examples at http://nvd3.org/livecode/#codemirrorNav but it didn't change anything

Comment: Actually, when I change their live example it breaks the line and it just lays across the bottom of the graph

Comment: That's because in their example the magnitudes of the domains are so different. To do what you want, they would need to be roughly similar.

Comment: The figures I'm using on the graph can range quite a bit, the data I have at the moment to test it is small though and doesn't go above 25 or below 0, but the line still doesn't seem to use the Y1Axis. I'll try uploading a JSFiddle to make it a bit easier

Comment: Hi Lars, here's a JSFiddle of the problem I'm experiencing. I have added the line you posted just before the `return chart;` but it doesn't seem to be making any difference, except I can't hover over some of the points on the line while that code is in place http://jsfiddle.net/S43qg/8/

Comment: Not sure what's going on there -- are you using an old version of NVD3? It works fine for me in the live code thing.

Comment: Just noticed in the live code version on the NVD3 site they're using d3.v2.js, but in the download it is d3.v3.js. Changed this and it works fine. Is there a huge amount of difference between the 2 or should I be OK using v2? Thanks very much for your help Lars

Comment: Well, there's quite a number of differences, but if you want to use NVD3 then you don't really have a choice.

Answer (score 0):

Much like Lars' answer, this leaves a gap where the axis used to be, but I hid this with CSS.

```
.y2-axis {display: none}
```