# NVD3 & D3.js - Remove Y2 Axis and Scale Second Graph

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm using nv.d3.js and d3.v3.js and working off [this model](http://nvd3.org/ghpages/linePlusBar.html) example.

I want to remove the Y2 axis and have the bar and line chart work off the same data. So, they should be working off the same scale.

Note: I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20075708/nvd3-d3-js-how-to-remove-y2-axis) very related post and tried the solution given there. The below code was provided in that link. I implemented into my code and it didn't work, apparently because I am working with d3.v3 and not d3.v2.

```
chart.y2Axis.scale().domain(chart.y1Axis.scale().domain());
```

This line of code made some difference though. If I hover my mouse over the displayed points, they no longer enlarge. If I hover my mouse over the bottom of the x-axis the points enlarge. This seems to hint that the line chart points are being re-scaled but not redrawn.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

EDIT / UPDATE: If anyone is trying to do the same thing, I simply used d3.json() twice! See below:

```
d3.json("data.json",function(error,data) {
nv.addGraph(function() {  
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
....
....
return chart;
});

});

d3.json("data2.json",function(error,data) {
nv.addGraph(function() {
var chart = nv.models.linePlusBarChart()
....
....
return chart;
});

});
```

Comment: Have you tried passing in the same data twice?

Comment: Yes that's what I ended up doing!